# You did not supply a value for binding 7

Tags: python, sqlite

I am having "You did not supply a value for binding 7" error, however,
I have checked similar questions already but none of them seemed to have the same issue that I am facing.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('SchoolDB.db')
cursors = con.cursor()

cursors.execute("""INSERT INTO PARENTS (STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME,GENDER,DOB,QUALIFICATION,EMAIL,PHONE_CODE, MOBILE, OCCUPATIONS) VALUES(:sid,:pfn,:psn,:pgdr,:pdob,:qlf,:pem,:ppcd,:pmb,:ocp)""",{"sid":student_id,"pfn":ParentName, "psn":ParentSurname,"pgdr":ParentGender, "pdob":ParentDOB, "qlf":ParentQualification, "epm":ParentEmail, "ppcd":ParentPhoneCode, "pmb":ParentMobile, "ocp":ParentOccupation})

con.commit()
```

Comment: You have mistyped something. pem != epm

Comment: oh!!!, that seems to be right, thanks.

Comment: @OldBill, maybe you can move your comment to answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistyped something. pem != epm